# tilde char on IDLE 3.2.2 MacOS-X Lion

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

Impossible to get tilde char ~ on Python IDLE 3.2.2 MacOS-X Lion.
I tried the prefs/Keys, no success, no entry "Option-N space".
Please help !

Answer (score 2):

I often have the same problem as well - my IDLE crashes immediately when I am trying to use Option-N.

If you want to use it in a string, you can replace it using

```
"\x007E"
```

instead of

```
"~"
```

Unfortunately, if you want to use it in your code, for example as a bitwise NOT operation, this is not possible either.
Try opening another program (your browser, TextEdit or any other software which supports using Option-N), type the tilde char there and copy it into idle.

Comment: +1 that write and paste thing is a somewhat primitive solution but it also rescued my many times from desperation.